# What is the best rich textarea editor for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, richtextbox

Something like this one on the Stackoverflow site would be nice!

Or something non-jQuery that doesn't conflict with jQuery $() tags would be great.

Comment: I posted a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180827/unobtrusive-javascript-rich-text-editor

Comment: Starter kit you can play with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092137/creating-a-text-editor-through-jquery/62903900#62903900

Answer (score 27):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned **[markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)**:

*markItUp! is a JavaScript plugin built on the jQuery library. It allows you to turn any textarea into a markup editor. Html, Textile, Wiki Syntax, Markdown, BBcode or even your own Markup system can be easily implemented.*

[image]

Comment: Markitup is great, but it's not really a rich editor. It just adds buttons to a normal textarea. When people say "rich editor," they generally mean WYSIWYG.

Comment: Jeremy B did mention it about 4 months before your answer.  Guess a picture is worth a dozen votes. :)

Comment: @Great Turtle My answer is like the iPhone 4, and has the glass effect

Comment: The bottom pane gives you a preview, it's 1/2 WYSIWYG

Comment: Try this: [link](http://jqueryte.com).

Answer (score 15):

For me [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)
is an excellent editor. It does rich text as a markup editor and allows you to use different standards: html, wiki, UBB, etc...  It also allows plugins very easily.

Answer (score 11):

IMHO tinyMce and ckeditors are way too bloated.
I've tried a lot of different editors that would be jquery plugins and the best one to my taste is HtmlBox.
It's extremely small = 14Kb minified (without icons) and unobtrusive.

I've tried all of these:
1. Avidan editor
2. Wymeditor
3. ueditor
4. RTE Jquery
5. jwysiwyg (GNU2)
6. jhtml area (Microsoft public license)
7. htmlbox (mit license)
8. TinyMCE (gnu)
9. Ckeditor (as well as FCKeditor)

Answer (score 8):

CLEditor is an open source jQuery plugin which provides a lightweight (just over 9K with icons), full featured, cross browser, extensible, WYSIWYG HTML editor that can be easily added into any web site. http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor

Comment: Finally someone made this work with jQuery! Really liked NicEdit, but now that this is here and works in jQuery, I can be more pure. Love this thing. Must use on my next project.

Comment: Very nice and minimalistic editor.

Answer (score 7):

I personaly use FCK because Tiny MCE does't handle html editing well, small changes in html produce lots of unececary html tags.

Answer (score 6):

For full on html (rather than WMD style b / i / a) I normally use http://www.fckeditor.net/. Customisation can be a little cumbersome, but reliable once in place.

Answer (score 3):

- [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/) (What You See Is What You Mean) is a jQuery plugin.
- [jWysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/) is an alternative with much less features

Answer (score 3):

I really like Yahoo's [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/).

Answer (score 3):

here you can find 10 jquery and Non-jquery Text Editors:
[www.queness.com](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)

Answer (score 2):

WMD looks good. too bad it does not use jquery framework.
TinyMce is pretty large and could slow down the page load..

look at this post:
http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

hope it helps

-Towfiq I.

Answer (score 1):

i personally use TinyMCE in our project, easy to integrate and use.

Answer (score 1):

ENDORSEMENT: TinyMCE is mature, actively maintained, and well documented. It is easily extended and generates decent, valid XHTML while editing. I've been using it in applications for the past three years because of these reasons. I've tried all the other editors mentioned above but I've kept using TinyMCE. The other editors simply don't do enough or the ramp up to functionality extension is too steep (the exception being the YUI Editor).

CRITICISM: TinyMCE will not interoperate 100% smoothly with the ASP.Net ScriptManager and UpdatePanel controls (at no fault of the TinyMCE script). The overall size of all the TinyMCE scripts can add up to over 1 MB, but plug-in scripts are loaded as needed when in use.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best one non.jQuery and $() conflict free would be the dijit.Editor from Dojo Toolkit. Take a look [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Editor.html#dijit-editor)

Answer (score 1):

Markupit is best for me, and found here great list of only jQuery based Rich Text Editors: http://smashingwall.com/tools/jquery-rich-text-editors/

Answer (score 0):

Tiny MCE is the best IMHO - I have tired a ton of them and Tiny has the best over features, easy to create content templates, easy to set which CSS is shown in the editor and used to display it, very large API, great skins, ect...

Answer (score 0):

[WYM](http://www.wymeditor.org) Editor could be a reasonable solution. It generates XHTML strict W3C XHTML hope can help you .

Answer (score 0):

[Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) is an upcoming HTML inplace editor. Its customizable as well to write our own plugins.

FYI: Drawback is that it has ~1MB of js file, if all the features are required. But, could be reduced by removing unwanted plugins.