# how to use tinymce and jquery 

Tags: jquery, tinymce

who can give me a simple code ,

i want a simplest way to create a rich textarea,

thanks

this is my code,and not successful :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> 
</head> 
    <body>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 

        </style> 
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
</form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/example.css",
    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",
    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the TinyMCE site?  http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blatantly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207774/what-is-the-best-rich-textarea-editor-for-jquery/207784#207784), but have a look at:

<strike>http://dev.jquery.com/wiki/Plugins/tinyMCE</strike>

Edit: No longer uses jQuery: http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck using jwysiwyg instead of tinyMCE.

http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/

Answer (score 0):

With TinyMCE 4 there is jQuery integration:

```
$('textarea.edit').tinymce({
    // put object passed to tinymce.init
});
```

or

```
$('textarea.edit').tinymce();
```

to get instance of the tinyMCE if you already created the editor.

if you look at `tineymce_x.x.x_dev.zip` you will find file `/tinymce/src/core/src/main/js/JqueryIntegration.js` with the source code for the plugin.