# Is it possible to have several different textcolors in one textarea?

Tags: html, css

I'd like several words / phases in a textarea to appear in different colors... How would I go about doing this? Below is an example, I'd like the word green to appear green etc etc...

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%; resize: none;">
Is it possible to have multiple colors in a textarea? 
How would i set certain phases or words to be different colors? 
"Green"
"Red"
"Blue"
</textarea>
```

Comment: Actually there is one solution without contenteditable, see here: [How to change the background color of the modified text in a text area](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39902858/1066234) or https://css-tricks.com/creating-an-editable-textarea-that-supports-syntax-highlighted-code/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do this *inside* a `<textarea>`, not one that's editable.  It sounds like you're after a [WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), most of which use a `<iframe>` to do this.

There are several JavaScript options for this, to name a few:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Sure you can! in-fact what you call a "rich text-box" editor is an editable div, highlighted using CSS or inline-styling (all of WordPress plugins, MCE and editors work this way. See answer below.

Answer (score 42):

You cannot do this with a textarea or input tag. However, as @naikus mentioned, you can use the contenteditable attribute. It is as follows:

```
<div id="mytxt" contenteditable="true">
   Hello, my name is <span style="color: blue;">Bob</span>
   and I have a friend name <span style="color: green;">Joe</span>.
</div>
```

```html
<div id="mytxt" contenteditable="true">
       Hello, my name is <span style="color: blue;">Bob</span> and I have a friend name <span style="color: green;">Joe</span>.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think its possible to do that with a textarea and html alone. What you need is a Rich Text box
You can either [roll your own](https://web.archive.org/web/20161208201749/http://www.geekpedia.com:80/tutorial198_Creating-a-Rich-Text-Editor-using-JavaScript.html) by modifying an iframe, or use the [popular ones available](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)

Other option you can have when you target html5 enabled browsers is the [contentEditable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) attribute. You can use it to make a textbox-like control

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in a normal textarea.

- For syntax highlighting-like approaches, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly).
- For a more complicated, full-fledged WYSIWYG solution that can do colours as well as other formatting, images, etc., see a WYSIWYG editor like [CKEditor](http://www.ckeditor.com).

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible with current w3c specs. If you're looking for a workaround, check [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) or [editArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html) for their workarounds for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with default html controls. You can use Rich Text Box editors to get what you want, for example check this question:

[What is the best rich textarea editor for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207774/what-is-the-best-rich-textarea-editor-for-jquery)