# Multi Color Text Area

Tags: html, css

I would like to have different colored text in my textarea as user inputs on it based on a set of predefined array of strings. Is it possible or is there any custom library with the help of which we can make create multiple colored text in textarea.

Comment: use JS/jQuery for this feature

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have several different textcolors in one textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435167/is-it-possible-to-have-several-different-textcolors-in-one-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're after a **[WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)** editor, which most of them use an `<iframe>` to do this.

Have a look at the following:

**[tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)**

**[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add styling to a plain textarea. You would have to go with an existing rich text editor, or build your own editor.

I would recommend using an existing editor.
There are several rich text editors out there. Check out the Telerik control suite.