# How to style every word with different color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is converting entire input to single color, but not individual colors to individual words. Here is my fiddle where only red gets applied to entire input.
Test Input: hi hello etc. When I clear the input field, the last color is applied to the first word but not the red color.
The function is

```
function func(e){
    var content = text.innerHTML;
    if( e.keyCode === 32){
      text.style.color = colors[i++];
     }
}
```

Here is the fiddle : [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6e31d7d8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have several different textcolors in one textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435167/is-it-possible-to-have-several-different-textcolors-in-one-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `input` tag words can't have different colors, since text and input are not separate elements, but for other elements you can wrap each word into `span` and add style to them, that is how **rich content editors** are working.

Assume you have `<p id="paragraph">Here are few words</p>` and you want to add different colors to each word.

You can `split` innerText of `#paragraph` and create span for each word and insert result as innerHTML of `#paragraph`.

Here is example

```js
var paragrapgh = document.getElementById("paragraph");
var words = paragrapgh.innerText.split(" "); // here I am spliting words by space i.e tokenizing it
var colors = ["red","green","blue","pink", "gold", "yellow", "blueviolet"];
var spans = [];

for(var x = 0; x < words.length; x++){
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)] // geting random color from array;
    var span = "<span style='background-color: " + color + ";'>" + words[x] + "</span>"
    
    spans.push(span);
}

// setting colored spans as paragraph HTML
paragrapgh.innerHTML = spans.join(" ");
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Here are few words</p>
```

Also you can use [`contenteditable`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute to elements to allow users to edit content of element as it is input.

So you can try to use `contenteditable` div with `keyup` event and make your styling of words.

Comment: Is it possible to apply color when the user is inputting in the `contenteditable` element?

Comment: Yes, you can create logic so that it will change color of new text

Answer (score 1):

Using div you can kind of achieve it. The below code has few issues like caret position

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var newWord = '';
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "darkpink"];
var prevValue = '';
var i = 0;
text.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  func(event)
});


function func(e) {
  newWord = newWord + e.key;
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    prevValue = text.innerHTML = prevValue + '<span style="color:' + colors[i++] + '">' + newWord + '</span>';
    newWord = '';
    if (i == 3) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#text {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" class="highlight" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer:
You cannot; styles will apply to the whole input only. If you want to achieve this you need a control that support Rich Text Editing.

Comment: @can we do it using  a text area?

Comment: Unfortunately not with plain old HTML controls. You need to use a third party library such as http://ckeditor.com and Inline Editing.

Comment: @RandikaRatnayake: No, you do not *need* to use a third party library, they are doing the same thing suggested by Aren's answer, using `contenteditable`.

Comment: Agree. Do someone needs to reinvent the wheel when there are readily available components :)