# Matching and highlighting tags/words (changing color and font-weight) inside textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've `textarea` where I just start typing when I add `tags` which I define in array so based on my condition it should say `in array` but it is saying `not in array` here is my example code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tagsArray = new Array("{full_name}", "{email}", "{company}", "{reg_no}", "{address}", "{city}", "{mobile}", "{rec1_full_name}", "{rec1_email}", "{rec2_full_name}", "{rec2_email}");
  var txtArea = $("textarea#txtarea").val();
  $(document).on("keyup", "#txtarea", function() {
    if ($.inArray(txtArea, tagsArray) != -1) {
      console.log("in array");
    } else {
      console.log("not in array");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtarea" name="txtarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

I just start typing this text `This is not what we want {email} {rec1_full_name}` although my email tag is typed in textarea but it is showing message `not in array` so how to match my tags during typing and after match the tags I have to change its color to blue and its font to bold.

Comment: on what element are you using the keyup?

Comment: there is a textarea.

Comment: $("textarea").on("keyup" , function(){ //DO_THIS });

Comment: I've code like this `$(document).on(".textarea", "keyup", function() { //code here });` now I can't figure out what to do in `//code here` area or in  function and I also tried `blur` instead of `keyup` function.

Comment: you want to have some text displayed bold with a blue color. so use $("element").css({color: "blue",fontWeight: "bold"});

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior did you read my question???

Comment: Ok, I just read the updated question.. trying to figure it out.

Comment: I just update code at my local machine and add loop and count length then use `inArray` function but not work for me.

Comment: first it should tell me during typing the tags are match or not after match I'll change its color and font will be bold.

Comment: check my answer @kamgaSimoJunior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you. Hope this will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="txtarea" name="txtarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
<div id="displayContainer"></div>

<style type="text/css">
  .bold-blue{
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tagsArray = new Array("{full_name}", "{email}", "{company}", "{reg_no}", "{address}", "{city}", "{mobile}", "{rec1_full_name}", "{rec1_email}", "{rec2_full_name}", "{rec2_email}");

   $("#txtarea").on('keyup', function(e) {

      var tags = $("#txtarea").val().match("{(.*)}");

   //check whether the entered tag is valid
      for (tag in tags){
         if(!inArray(tags[tag], tagsArray)){
            if(tags[tag][0] == "{" && tags[tag][tags[tag].length-1] == "}"){
               //alert the user that he entered an invalid tag
               alert(tags[tag]+" is not a valid tag.");
            }
         }
      }
    });
   //render the tags blue and bold
     $("#submitBtn").on("click", function(){
      var tags = $("#txtarea").val().match("{(.*)}");
        var text = $("#txtarea").val();
        for (tag in tags){
          if(tags[tag][0] == "{" && tags[tag][tags[tag].length-1] == "}"){
           var newText = text.replace( tags[tag], '<span class="bold-blue">'+tags[tag]+'</span>');
          }
        }
        $("#displayContainer").html( newText );

     });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of clicking button can I show my `bold` and `blue` `tags` in `textarea` instead of showing it in `displayContainer` `div`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code doesn't work since you read the value of textarea once and this variable is not changing while you are typing;

2) Using [`$.inArray(txtArea, tagsArray)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) you are trying to if the full string is contained in the array which is not correct. Using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for this would be much better:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tagsArray = new Array("{full_name}", "{email}", "{company}");   
    $('textarea#txtarea').on('keyup', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var searchExp = new RegExp(tagsArray.join("|"),"gi");
        if(searchExp.test(val)) {
            console.log("in array");
        } else {
            console.log("not in array");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
 <textarea id="txtarea" name="txtarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

3) You can't apply styling to the separate words withing the textarea. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435167/is-it-possible-to-have-several-different-textcolors-in-one-textarea). Probably you will need to have some other approach, for example something [like this](https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR) - the idea here is to have a `div` element as background and sync content between this element and `textarea`.

**UPDATE:** 
4) You can try to use [`contenteditable="true"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) on the `div` element and this will the inner content editable, so your `div` could behave like a rich text editor. Here is a quick example on how this could be achieved. Hope this idea will help you (I'm not going to write the full functionality for you, just want to illustrate the concept and what options do you have with your issue).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tagsArray = new Array("{full_name}", "{email}", "{company}");   
    $('div#txtarea').on('keyup', function() {
        var $this = $(this); 
        //remember position of cursor before changing the content of the div element
        var restoreCursorPosition = saveCaretPosition(this);
        var val = $this.text(); 

        //highlight tags
        $this.html(val.replace(new RegExp(tagsArray.join("|"), "gi"), "<mark>$&</mark>"));
        //resore cursor position
        restoreCursorPosition();
    });
    
    function saveCaretPosition(context){
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        range.setStart(context, 0 );
        var len = range.toString().length;

        return function restore(){
            var pos = getTextNodeAtPosition(context, len);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            var range = new Range();
            range.setStart(pos.node ,pos.position);
            selection.addRange(range);

        }
    }

    function getTextNodeAtPosition(root, index){
        var lastNode = null;

        var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,function next(elem) {
            if(index > elem.textContent.length){
                index -= elem.textContent.length;
                lastNode = elem;
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
            }
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        });
        var c = treeWalker.nextNode();
        return {
            node: c? c: root,
            position: c? index:  0
        };
    }
});
```

```css
div#txtarea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

mark {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
 <div id="txtarea" name="txtarea" contenteditable="true">
  Test input!
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to change the color of match tags and its font style???

Comment: @user3833682 Have you seen 3rd paragraph in my answer? You can't simply do this using `textarea`! See updates with some concept of how you can achieve this. with `div` and `contenteditable` attribute set to true.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {

var yourstring =$("P").html().match("{(.*)}")

   
for (i=0; i< yourstring.length; i++){

$('p:contains('+yourstring[i]+')', document.body).each(function(){
      
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
            new RegExp(yourstring[i], 'g'), '<span class=someclass>'+yourstring[i]+'</span>'
      ));
});
}
});
```

```css
.someclass {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply {email} {rec1_email} dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, printe book.
</p>
<div>
```

Comment: I'm using jquery's it should be done with `keyup` or `blur` function.

Comment: when I'm typing I just add tags during typing like `{email}` and it should automatically bold and color should be blue.

Comment: This code will update color every string which contains {}

Comment: @user3833682 For the question you have posted earlier above one is the answer. If you have new question you have to post it as a new one.

Comment: @MrASquare question is same first I didn't upload my code then I updated my question and added code now.

Answer (score 0):

Using keyup you can apply styles whatever you want and onfocus() your

tag will be editable

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('P').on("click", function () {
            $('P').attr("contenteditable", "true");
        });
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            var str = $('P').html();
            $('P').attr("contenteditable", false);
            var words = ["{full_name}", "{email}", "{company}", "{reg_no}", "{address}", "{city}", "{mobile}", "{rec1_email}"]

            var reg = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi')
            var p = document.createElement('p')
            p.innerText = str
            $('P').html($('P').html().replace(reg, '<b style="color:blue">$&</b>'));
        }
        else {
            $('P').attr("contenteditable", true);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply {email} {rec1_email} dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, printe book.
    </p>
<div>
```

Comment: This code is showing `HTML` code instead of tags should be in bold and color should be changed.

Comment: When you put string in <p> it will be showing in styles applied

Comment: But I'm doing this in textarea can you please do that on textarea base?

Comment: It's not possible to show html code in Textarea. but with use of contenteditable attribute, you can do same thing on <P> or <Div> tag

Comment: You can do the same thing on focus out also which functionality is right now on key up