# Hide only the content of an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span overlapping my input field, that updates its content as you type into the input field.

Even though I positioned the span perfectly on the input text, you can still see that the text is a little more bold and letters are thicker.

[image]

(field nr.1- with span, nr.2- without)

I tried hiding the entire input field, but then also the cursor disappears, without which typing is very confusing.

Is there a way that I could hide only the text of the input field?

Comment: Why do you even need that span?

Comment: Your span's background is probably still transparent, which is the default. Set the span's background to white to hide the input.

Comment: I need it to manipulate the color, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233743/javascript-how-to-change-color-to-only-part-of-the-string-in-an-input-field

Comment: _“you can still see that the text is a little more bold and letters are thicker”_ - well then you should probably start by applying the same font properties to the input field and the span (which at least from browser default stylesheets is rather likely not going to be the case.)

Comment: fair point, I was just wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this than overlapping two texts

Comment: rather, you can set span:hover {cursor:text;} in your css

Comment: @Cruiser: The OP means the insertion point in the text field, not the mouse cursor.

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš I don't like this approach (of manipulating color with span over the input field) since you wouldn't be able to select the words in input field with your mouse.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash hmm... it actually is possible, but it doesn't look very nice... I am open for different solution

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš yes, it doesn't work nice. I assume you can try using [`contenteditable="true"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) instead of your input. How to make it single line [is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831482/contenteditable-single-line-input). And in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675864/4222181) I've tried to make a basic example of words highlighting (see 4) in `contenteditable="true"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your input text invisible and the cursor black by:

```css
  #box {
      color: transparent;
      caret-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box" value="some_sample_text">
```

So this way the text is invisible but the currsor shows up. With your span overlaying this should be exactly what you want. But don´t forget your input field must have the same size and fontsize or the caret is on the wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some time, here's what I landed on:

```css
input{
  position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
#bottom {
  z-index: 1;
}
#top {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
<input type="text" id="bottom" value="bottom_box">
<input type="text" id="top" value="top_box">
</div><br>
```

Comment: If you have a sample code or something please mention it too. So that we can understand the whole problem