# Highlight search results using angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, search, highlight, angularjs-filter

I have a simple table and every next row is added by clicking "Append" button.

I need to highlight matches between search input field with table input fields.

Trying to use `highlight` filter to achieve this, but it it runs with an error:

`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"`

How could I fix it? Example code below:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

            app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
                return function(text, phrase) {
                if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
                '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
                }
            });

            app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', 'highlightFilter', function($scope, highlightFilter){
                $scope.arr = [];
                $scope.append = function(){
                    var x = {};
                    x.data1 = "";
                    x.data2 = "";
                    $scope.arr.push(x); 
                };
            }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Author's List</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .highlighted { background: yellow }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button ng-click ="append()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Append</button>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.text">
                <ul>
                    <div ng-repeat="x in arr | filter:search.text" ng-bind-html="x.text | highlight:search.text"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form name ="myForm" novalidate> 
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>data1</th>
                        <th>data2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in arr">
                        <td><input ng-model="x.data1" required type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input ng-model="x.data2" required type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
           </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your filter takes input text as first parameter, but you are passing a field that is not defined on your model: `ng-bind-html="x.text | highlight:search.text"`. You have fields `data1` and `data2` but not `text`, that is why you are getting the mentioned error.

Your filter is actually working, but you have to pass a proper input parameter into it:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

            app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
                return function(text, phrase) {
                if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
                '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
                }
            });

            app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', 'highlightFilter', function($scope, highlightFilter){
                $scope.arr = [];
                $scope.append = function(){
                    var x = {};
                    x.data1 = "";
                    x.data2 = "";
                    $scope.arr.push(x); 
                };
            }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Author's List</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .highlighted { background: yellow }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button ng-click ="append()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Append</button>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.text">
                <br style="clear: both;"/>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in arr | filter:search.text">
                      <span ng-bind-html="x.data1 | highlight:search.text"></span>
                      <span ng-bind-html="x.data2 | highlight:search.text"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form name ="myForm" novalidate> 
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>data1</th>
                        <th>data2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in arr">
                        <td><input ng-model="x.data1" required type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input ng-model="x.data2" required type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
           </body>
```

Comment: thanks! any possibility to highlight in inputs directly?

Comment: @VladyslavPlakhuta no, since `input` supports only plain text. The only was is to emulate `input`s with `div` and `contenteditable="true"`. You can see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675864/4222181