# Do you know how to apply color to individual keywords in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Do you know how to apply color to individual keywords in textarea?

I want to place an underline instead of an alert in the textarea area for the banning

Comment: please elaborate or show us some examples and what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: As an example, I would like to tell you the color when I type a banner in the textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have several different textcolors in one textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435167/is-it-possible-to-have-several-different-textcolors-in-one-textarea)

Comment: I would like to add color for keyword words only in the textarea area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you really **can't**.

As `<input>` are self closing, they cannot accommodate any tags like `<span>` to add individual properties to.

You can however use some hacks.

[Some Hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435167/is-it-possible-to-have-several-different-textcolors-in-one-textarea)