# Dynamic span insertion in an editable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple syntax highlighter with typescript. Is there a way to insert css into a text with given indexes?

Let's say I have a textarea, and I want the color of the text at 0 to 10 to become red.
Is this even possible?

Comment: It should be noted that you can't have multiple colours in a Textarea. However, a good alternative could be https://stackoverflow.com/a/40898337/1544886

Answer (score 1):

```
const textarea = document.getElementById('yourTextareaId') as HTMLTextAreaElement;

function applyHighlight(start: number, end: number, color: string) {
    const before = textarea.value.substring(0, start);
    const highlighted = `<span style="color: ${color}">${textarea.value.substring(start, end)}</span>`;
    const after = textarea.value.substring(end);
    
    textarea.innerHTML = before + highlighted + after;
}

// forExsmple
applyHighlight(0, 10, 'red');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).