# jQuery RTE Recommendations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, richtextbox

There are some decent JavaScript-based RTEs out there, but when it comes to jQuery plugins, the selection seems to be quite sparse. What are the most recommended/promising projects (either finished, or in progress) that provide a simple-to-implement RTE using jQuery?

Here's what I've found from my research so far:

- [jQuery UI Rich Text Editor](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/RichTextEditor) is a planned component of Jquery UI, but appears to still be far from becoming a part of any upcoming release.
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) seems to have the best combination of features and ease to implement.
- [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) would be perfect for developers and power users, but isn't ideal for end-users unfamiliar with code

As you can see, my list is pretty short. Is there anything else out there, or soon-to-be out there that isn't listed yet?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180827/unobtrusive-javascript-rich-text-editor

Comment: Why is it important for you that your RTE uses jQuery?

Comment: spinon: I disagree: it's been getting on for 2 years since that question was asked, during which time new editors and new versions of old editors have come along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's important to you that your rich text editor uses jQuery, but one more you might like to consider is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/): it's pretty good and has [some kind of jQuery integration component](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery). If you're going to be developing plug-ins, be aware that while the architecture is very flexible, the developer documentation is sparse.

Comment: It's not *really* important, and by no means essential, but having my JS stack for a given project all built upon the same framework seemed appealing.